# Splitting polygon using another polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, splitting

I have two polygon layers (yellow and orange in the attached image).

I am wondering if there is a way to get a count of the number of isolated areas that the orange polygon has divided the yellow polygon into using QGIS?

I have tried using various vector processing tools in QGIS but have yet to find one that will produce the desired output. I am using QGIS version 3.4.

[image: screenshot of the two polygons I am working with]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple

Step One - "Vector> Geoprocessing> Difference";

Step Two - “Analysis Tools> Split Composite Objects” (This step is necessary in order to convert a multipolygon to a polygon, otherwise the result may not be accurate);

the third step "select a layer in the layers panel with the name" Single_parts ", click on the right mouse button and in the pop-up window set the checkbox - Show number of objects" and this is your result ...

Answer (score 3):

### The easy way

There is a very easy way to do so:

You can use `Vector` -> `Geoprocessing Tools` -> `Clip`.

`Input Layer` is the underlying, greenish one.

`Overlay Layer` is the clipping, orange one.

This will create a new layer (and if you leave the `Clipped` name empty, it will default to a temporary, disposable layer, so you don't pollute your hard drive).

The number of individual features of the clipped layer is the number you are looking for.

### The flexible way

You can avoid doing the manual count (useful if you have a large number of features) by using:

`Toolbox` (the "gear" icon) -> `Join attributes by location (summary)`

and inputting something like in the following screenshot:

[image: Join attributes by location (summary)]

Please note that, depending on the options you select, you can yield many more useful insights about the newly clipped polygons ;)

Comment: This seems to only creates an output layer that is the same as the overlay layer (orange one).

Comment: yes, because in your case the orange layer seems to only cut one contiguous feature of the yellow one.

Answer (score 0):

Use disolve tool with the box "Keep disjoint features separate" checked